# How do I track the status of a node.js request?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js application that generates an image, we'll say "Image A", and then uses "Image A" to generate another image, we'll call "Composition A". If the node server receives 4 image requests at around the same time for Composition A, Composition B, Composition C, etc. all of which will require image A (the exact same image). At the moment, in this scenario the server is regenerating "Image A" 4 times causing a really inefficient image request times.

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to only generate "Image A" once, and use it for the subsequent 4 image requests coming in at around the same time. The problem i'm running into is that the server requests are separate.

My plan is to try and set something up like "For server request #2 for image Composition B, wait for server request #1 Image A to be complete, then use that image instead of regenerating it. I'm not sure how to specifically use the node event system to check if the first request has finished, before continuing on with the subsequent requests.

### Illustration of current setup:

Frontend:

```
<img src="compositionA" />
<img src="compositionB" />
<img src="compositionC" />
<img src="compositionD" />
```

Server:

Request #1: 
Generate Image A --> Generate Composition A (using Image A)

Request #2:
Generate Image A --> Generate Composition B (using Image A)

Request #3:
Generate Image A --> Generate Composition C (using Image A)

Request #4:
Generate Image A --> Generate Composition D (using Image A)

Comment: You could just cache ImageA

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I were to cache Image A in Request #1, how could I tell request #2 to check if there is another request going on, and if there is, wait for it to finish, so it can use image A in the cache

Answer (score 0):

If identifier of the `Image A` is same across all the requests, why not pass the identifier as query param in the `Composition Image` URL, as follows:

```
<img src="compositionA?generatedImageId=<image-id>" />
<img src="compositionB?generatedImageId=<image-id>" />
<img src="compositionC?generatedImageId=<image-id>" />
<img src="compositionD?generatedImageId=<image-id>" />
```

If the `identifier` is unique in application, then, a LRU cache can be implemented on server. I will not go into code level details. But, I will give an outline of a possible solution.

1. Maintain a cache
2. One first call of a request, look into the cache.
3. Nothing will be there, as the cache is empty.
4. In that case, do the computation & cache the result mapped to the identifier.
5. Subsequent calls will utilize the previously computed value.

In this case, as the calls are happening simultaneously & the computation is asynchronous, a `Promise` of computation needs to be cached. This way, on first call, the promise can be cached immediately. Then the subsequent calls will wait on that promise. Once the promise is resolved for the first call, the remaining requests are served immediately.

Management(life time, expiry, etc.) of cache is a problem that needs to be dealt separately.
There can be different libraries found for that use case.
You can configure them for your needs.

Comment: I do have a query param that I pass, but I’m not sure how to use it to solve my issue. I don’t know how to tell the server “check and see if multiple requests that have this query key are happening at the same time”

Answer (score 0):

You need to do request 1 separately first and then do all the other requests.

For request 1, you should store it in cache like use a redis cache. And pass the cache key to every subsequent requests to fetch image A.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does seem like a viable method but I’d like to be able to handle this server side instead of forcing the client to get one url, wait until it’s back and then send the other requests.

Comment: Okay.  So instead of waiting for the response, why don't u set some timeout for the other requests so that the first request would have by that time stored it in the cache.